# Definition of the weight $k$ hyperbolic Laplacian

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, modular-forms, laplacian, differential-operators

I saw two different definitions for the weight $k$ non-Euclidean Laplacian.  First, in Daniel Bump's book *Automorphic Forms and Representations*, the following definitions are given for smooth $\mathbb C$-valued functions on the upper half plane (Chapter 2.1):

[image]

I was not able to verify (1.4) by the way.  Maybe I made a mistake, but from what I calculated, the first equality was not correct.  I was wondering whether one of the definitions (1.1), (1.2), (1.3) was not written correctly.

Edit: I have checked again, and (1.4) is actually correct.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_Maass_form#Definition) defines the weight $k$ non-Euclidean Laplacian by

$$\Delta_k = -y^2( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}) + iky (\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial}{\partial y})$$

Which definition is correct?

Comment: Just as a comment, there are some errata on that page (129): http://sporadic.stanford.edu/bump/match/errata.html

Comment: Those errors seem to have been fixed in my edition

Comment: Won't the first one lead to if $f(z)$ is smooth and $1$-periodic then $f(z) = \sum_n a_n(y) e^{2i \pi n x}$ and if it is in the kernel of $\Delta_k$ then $f(z) = c_0+\sum_{n\ne 0} c_n h_k(2\pi |n|y) e^{2i \pi n x}$ where $\partial_y^2 h_k(y) = h_k(y)+ h_k(y) C_k/ y$

Comment: I don't know..what is $(2\pi|n|y)$?

Comment: $h_k(t)$ evaluated at $t = 2 \pi N y$ with $N = |n|$. And $f(z) = c_0+\sum_{n\ne 0} c_n h_k(2\pi |n|y) e^{2i \pi n x}$ is what we need for the Mellin transform of $f(x+i.)-c_0$ being a Dirichlet series

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're saying.  You're saying because of that conclusion that Bump's definition is correct?

Comment: I'm saying Bump's definition leads to the Bessel function-Fourier series expansion of $1$-periodic smooth functions satisfying $\Delta_k f = 0$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maass_wave_form